# Nothing shows up in pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I really don't know how to handle this nothing shows up in my pygame window, not even the screen. The `fill()` line doesn't do anything. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
import pygame
def game():
    pygame.init()

    black = (0, 0, 0)
    green = (0,255,0)
    running = True
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    screen.fill(green)
    button_rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(200,150,100,50))

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

game()
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This stackoverflow questions should be helpful for you. :) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812433/pygame-sceen-fill-not-filling-up-the-color-properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812433/pygame-sceen-fill-not-filling-up-the-color-properly)

Comment: @ÁrpádCsepi That question doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to update the screen in the event loop.

```py
while running: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # Update the screen.
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: JEEEZ TYSM life saver

Comment: If the answer helps, you can accept it by clicking the green tick. I recommend you take the time to read the intro guide.